# Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down. Solr 7.5.0

Tags: solr

Im trying to setup a new Sitecore 9.2 site which requires me to set up Solr 7.5.0.

When I try to run the command `solr start` I can see the following error on `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/`

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    ... 17 more
```

Not sure on how to proceed. Ive checked the logs and im not see any additional information other then the same error im seeing in the browser.

Comment: `./bin/solr start -c -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983` try running it with the start path defined like so and let me know what you get. Replacing the example path to your actual path.

Comment: @Anicho I figured out the issue. My solr.xml was incorrect. It was edited incorrectly and had some text that wasnt supposed to be there...

Comment: I had an issue that gave me this message with the solr container. I _think_ it was because the local path to the repo had a dash in it (e.g. C:\dev\my-project). Once I removed the dash, the problem stopped and the container started cleanly. Hope this helps someone else pulling their hair out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out my solr.xml file was corrupted. Had some text in there that wasnt supposed to be there. So verify your solr.xml is correct... After looking at the logs closer I found this hidden.

`Config Exception during parsing file: null:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

This is what helped me.

Comment: I am stuck at similar issue. I can ran the command successfully ```./solr start -c -p 8983 -z 172.y.x.206:2181,172.x.y.205:2181,172.x.y.207:2181 -force``` But when I create collection uising ```./solr create_collection -c TEST -s 3 -rf 3 -force``` I get similar error as above

Comment: My `core.properties` was corrupt. Resetting it solved the issue.